# How to expand paragraph towards top when screen gets smaller and the content takes more space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on `ASP.NET MVC3` application using `Twitter-bootstrap` but I think that this problem is more likely to be solved with pure `CSS` still a `bootstrap` solution is also welcome.

I have a several links in my vertical menu (for the purpose of my example they are 3). Each menu has

```
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 40px;
```

The menu is within `<p>` and each paragraph is wrapped in div with:

```
 width: 30%;
```

Here is my [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj5Ak/). The problem is that as the screen get's smaller (smaller media, or just resizing) the menu is expanding towards the bottom but in my real design expanding is acceptable (desirable even) but I want this to happen towards the top of the page so the bottom line stays on the same level for all menus. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you explain it better? I think I have your solution but i´m a bit confused.

Comment: @DanielPanic Open the Fiddle link and start to shrink the output screen. As you are doing that you will notice that the middle menu (the one with the longest text) is increasing it's height because there's no place for the whole text. What I want is to change the direction that this height change is happening. Not going towards the bottom keeping the top borders at the same level, instead, I want the menu to increase towards top, keeping the bottom borders of all menus on the same level. Now the middle menu border is lower then the other two. I want it to be higher! Is that making sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to give it a height, since you only have width the browser only checks the X axis ! Try it out , `height:xx%;`

Comment: Could you be more specific. Give `height` to what? How much exactly? And also - there is link to a Fiddle example, maybe you could try your suggestion and see if it's working before posting an answer..